# url rewriting not working exactly on subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need a rewrite rule that rewrites

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/123/asdf
to
http://subdomain.domain.com/profile?id=123
```

I have a rule for this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]*)?$ profile.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

The problem is the above rule doesn't work the way i want it to. It rewrites the url's like below.

```
http://subdomain.domain.com
to
http://subdomain.domain.com/profile.php?id=
```

and

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/123/asdf
to
http://subdomain.domain.com/profile.php?id=123/asdf
```

The rewrite rule should not rewrite `subdomain.domain.com`.
The rule should only rewrite when the url looks like below.
 `http://subdomain.domain.com/123/asdf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/ profile.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: With a litte modification it worked fine...Thanks bro... 
**`RewriteRule ^([/-a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ profile.php?id=$1 [NC,L]`**
needed to add a / at the beginning of regex